# How can i shuffle a endless generator?

Tags: python, product, python-itertools

assume i have a generator with huge elements.

Actually, i want to produce a numeric expression machine:

it produce all possible numeric expressions:

```
oam = {'sub': [float, float], 'add':[float, float], 'ws_corr':[float, float, int], 'ws_rank':[float, int]}
rm  = {int: list(map(str, [1,2,3,4])), float:[o for o in oam] + ['lp', 'ap', 'vol']}

                                                                                                                                                                            
def gen_exp(depth):
  if depth > 0:
    for op in oam:
      for op_terms in it.product(*[rm[ret_type] for ret_type in oam[op]]):
        for op_term in it.product(*[[op_term] if op_term not in oam else gen_exp(depth-1) for op_term in op_terms]):
          yield '%s(%s)'%(op, ', '.join(map(str, op_term)))

print(list(gen_exp(1)))  # ['sub(lp, ap)', 'sub(lp, vol)', 'sub(ap, lp)', 'sub(ap, vol)', 'sub(vol, lp)', 'sub(vol, ap)', 'add(lp, ap)', 'add(lp, vol)', 'add(ap, lp)', 'add(ap, vol)', 'add(vol, lp)', 'add(vol, ap)', 'ws_corr(lp, ap, 1)', 'ws_corr(lp, ap, 2)', 'ws_corr(lp, ap, 3)', 'ws_corr(lp, ap, 4)', 'ws_corr(lp, vol, 1)', 'ws_corr(lp, vol, 2)', 'ws_corr(lp, vol, 3)', 'ws_corr(lp, vol, 4)', 'ws_corr(ap, lp, 1)', 'ws_corr(ap, lp, 2)', 'ws_corr(ap, lp, 3)', 'ws_corr(ap, lp, 4)', 'ws_corr(ap, vol, 1)', 'ws_corr(ap, vol, 2)', 'ws_corr(ap, vol, 3)', 'ws_corr(ap, vol, 4)', 'ws_corr(vol, lp, 1)', 'ws_corr(vol, lp, 2)', 'ws_corr(vol, lp, 3)', 'ws_corr(vol, lp, 4)', 'ws_corr(vol, ap, 1)', 'ws_corr(vol, ap, 2)', 'ws_corr(vol, ap, 3)', 'ws_corr(vol, ap, 4)', 'ws_rank(lp, 1)', 'ws_rank(lp, 2)', 'ws_rank(lp, 3)', 'ws_rank(lp, 4)', 'ws_rank(ap, 1)', 'ws_rank(ap, 2)', 'ws_rank(ap, 3)', 'ws_rank(ap, 4)', 'ws_rank(vol, 1)', 'ws_rank(vol, 2)', 'ws_rank(vol, 3)', 'ws_rank(vol, 4)']
```

this generator is very huge, when the depth comes to 2, the expr num is more than 10^8
So, it can be considered as a endless generator.

as you can see, the generator is built by a for-loop like method.

So, the problem is, it's too ordered.

I want it to be more random(because the similar expression may have the similar result, i want it to visit the different in the first), but need to keep the completeness.

So, how can i shuffle it?

Comment: why don't you build randomness into the generator itself? perhaps as a kwarg option. You could shuffle your iterables in each of the layers of for loops

Comment: @MZ, each layers is to loop a genereator(product), so the problem still will be loop a generator.

Comment: oam doesn't seem to be a generator.

Comment: @MZ, oh, that's true. Thanks for remindering! but let's see if there is more randomly method, since the first loop random may not be the randomest

Comment: @MZ, that' s a mistake, it is still a product, sorted_product is my function, but still be a generator

Comment: Do you want "more random" or do you want actually random? It isn't clear just what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JohnColeman, actually random is the best, but, if it's not possible, more random is better

Comment: With a genuinely endless generator, I don't know if the idea of a random permutation of its elements has a clear sense (e.g. -- what is a random permutation of the integers? There are likely to be different probability distributions you can put on the space of all such permutations). On the other hand, for finite but too large to hold in memory, there might not be any effective way to make the last generated item appear first (which it would have to do sometimes if the permutations are random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use `islice` to slice off an initial segment of the generator as a pool of items waiting to be given, shuffle that, and return items from it, periodically adding more items to the pool.

Proof of concept:

```
import itertools,random

def quasi_permute(gen,pool_size):
    more = True
    pool = list(itertools.islice(gen,pool_size))
    random.shuffle(pool)
    while(len(pool) > 0):
        yield pool.pop()
        if len(pool) <= pool_size//2 and more:
            more_items = list(itertools.islice(gen,pool_size//2))
            pool.extend(more_items)
            random.shuffle(pool)
            if len(more_items) < pool_size//2:
                more = False

#test:

def genrange(n):
    yield from range(n)

print(list(quasi_permute(genrange(10),4)))

#typical output: [2, 0, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 7]
```

Another test looked like:

```
>>> p = quasi_permute(genrange(10**8),10**5)
>>> list(itertools.islice(p,10))
[79324, 80142, 42905, 67430, 26030, 31212, 77972, 71626, 61142, 45597]
```